# SIMPLE – Animate Multiple SVGs in Sequence (like a looping GIF)

Tags: svg, gif, svg-animate

I am trying to do the most basic **SVG animation**, and everything I've found is trying to teach me keyframes and advanced stuff like that. I understand keyframes from working in After Effects and that's not what I need at all.

All I want to do is animate the same 8 svg paths in a sequence, like a flip book, in which I can edit the loop speed easily. I want the image to change colors, so I would repeat the same 8 SVGs just saved with a different color, or maybe there's a better way to do that with the code, I don't know. I have included a sample GIF that I made demonstrating the exact effect I am looking for. Basically I want to recreate that GIF in scalable SVG format. What you see is 8 separate drawings.

[image]

I want to display this animation on my website as the main graphic, so it needs to be scalable.

I need to do this as soon as humanly possible for my portfolio review.

Comment: I have the SVGs created. I made them in Illustrator. Sorry, I should've been clearer. I can get the code for every frame too, I just need to know how to animate them...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of animating 8 SVG frames using CSS.

We make the group element (ie. the frame) visible for 1/8th (12.5%) of a second, then hide it again, using a `@keyframe` definition.  Each subsequent frame has it's animation delayed for an 0.125 seconds, so that they appear in sequence.

```css
svg {
  width: 300px;
}

#frame1 {
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: 1s show infinite;
}

#frame2 {
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: 1s show infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.125s;
}

#frame3 {
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: 1s show infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
}

#frame4 {
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: 1s show infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.375s;
}

#frame5 {
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: 1s show infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

#frame6 {
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: 1s show infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.625s;
}

#frame7 {
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: 1s show infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.75s;
}

#frame8 {
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: 1s show infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.865s;
}

@keyframes show {
  0%   { visibility: visible;}
  12.5%  { visibility: visible; }
  12.6%  { visibility: hidden; }
  100% { visibility: hidden; }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <g id="frame1">
    <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="25"/>
  </g>
  <g id="frame2">
    <circle cx="250" cy="50" r="25"/>
  </g>
  <g id="frame3">
    <circle cx="250" cy="150" r="25"/>
  </g>
  <g id="frame4">
    <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="25"/>
  </g>
  <g id="frame5">
    <circle cx="150" cy="250" r="25"/>
  </g>
  <g id="frame6">
    <circle cx="50" cy="250" r="25"/>
  </g>
  <g id="frame7">
    <circle cx="50" cy="150" r="25"/>
  </g>
  <g id="frame8">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Paul LeBeau, thanks so much, this really helped. My SVGs are quite complex and I believe this is causing a minor problem. One frame turns all white areas black, so it's a little glitchy. Any idea how I can fix this? Here's a link to the sandbox... http://cssdeck.com/labs/opmpfvdt

Comment: It seems to be affecting frame 7, but frame7 is okay if you delete the first six frames.  I suspect it is a copy and paste error. If you go to the bottom of your sample, you can see the `</svg>` is red. That suggests that there is some bad nesting going on. You are probably missing a `</g>` somewhere, and frame7 is inheriting a `fill` from a previous frame - turning the white teeth black.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau There is a `<g>` left within frame3. Furthermore, teeth does not become black after replacing `st2` with `st1` within frame7. However, after these two problems are corrected, there still feels flickering once per cycle. Could you help to comment the reason and the workaround ? :D

Comment: Are you talking about your own animation that you have created?  Then no, I can't really help debug an animation I can't see.  Create a new question and include your animation. Maybe we can help you then.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make it a single image. It doesn't even require CSS. You can use a plain text editor to add an SVG animation with `calcMode` set to `discrete` to [animate the `viewBox`](/questions/33820012/animate-svg-viewbox-change).